# Promise , object literal , API java Script

Tags: javascript, object, async-await, promise, iteration

Ok, I think I am doing the promise wrong. I have 2 problems:

- The results inside the class is working not problem. but when I retaive it at app.js it is showing as a promise.
- The results inside the classrooms should be more than one row/object but it is only giving me one result

I am able to get the output I want inside the class, but in the following app.js I get this when I try to retraive the results values :
**Promise {}**

> ```
> let results
> document.getElementById('crypto').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
>   const cryptoInput = e.target.value;
>   console.log(cryptoInput);
>   if (cryptoInput.length > 2) {
>     results = crypto.getPrice(currency, cryptoInput)
>     //here I get Promise {<pending>}
>     console.log(results)
>   }
> })
>
> const table = document.getElementById('resultsTable');
> let i = 0;
> function showOptions(results) {
>   console.log(results)
> }
> ```

the class is working :

```
class CoinGecko {
  constructor() {
  }

  async list() {
    const list1 = await fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=false`);
    
    const list2 = await fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=2&sparkline=false`);
    
    const list1Json = await list1.json();
    const list2Json = await list2.json();
    const list = Object.assign(list1Json, list2Json);
    //const list = list1Json.concat(list2Json);
    return list;
    //console.log(list);
  }
  

  async getPrice(currency = 'usd', crypto) {
    let results=[];
     const toutCrypto = await this.list().then(res => {
      Object.keys(res).forEach(function (element){
      
        if (res[element].id.startsWith(crypto) ||
          res[element].name.startsWith(crypto) ||
          res[element].symbol.startsWith(crypto))
        { 
          //console.log();
          results.push({
            id: res[element].id,
            name: res[element].name,
            image: res[element].image,
            symbol: res[element].symbol,
            price: res[element].current_price,
            date: res[element].last_updated,
          })
          console.log(results[0])
        } 
      });  
     });
    console.log(results[0].id)
    
    return {
        results
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code, please?

Comment: I did edit it and the code is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the late answer
add await to your async function

```js
results = await crypto.getPrice(currency, cryptoInput)
```

you are using an async function but not waiting for the response, that's why you get promise as a result

I tested the code, here is an example result:
[image]

edit: as [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) says, you need to make your event listener async

```js
document.getElementById("crypto").addEventListener("keyup", async (e) => {
```

Comment: I'd figure OP would see that, I'll edit the answer anyways, thank you

Comment: thank you , Yes that was the problem